# Validating a solution for a differential equation with DiracDelta

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, physics

For the following differential equation

$\displaystyle-\frac{∂ ^2\phi2 (x)}{∂ x^2}+λ ~[\phi2 (x)]^3-\mu ^2~\phi2 (x)=\phi2(x)~δ(x)$

```
-D[ϕ2[x], {x, 2}] - μ^2*ϕ2[x] + λ*ϕ2[x]^3 == ϕ2[x]*DiracDelta[x]
```

One possible solution for $\phi2[x]$ is given by $\text{$\phi $2}(\text{x})\text{:=}\displaystyle\frac{\mu  \tanh \left(\frac{\mu  \sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{λ }}$

```
ϕ2[x_] := (μ/Sqrt[λ])*Tanh[(Sqrt[x^2]*μ)/Sqrt[2]]
```

The following command (hopefully?) validates the solution:

```
Simplify[-D[ϕ2[x], {x, 2}] - μ^2*ϕ2[x] + λ*ϕ2[x]^3 == ϕ2[x]*DiracDelta[x]]

(*True*)
```

Apparently, another identity/solution is when the RHS is replaced by $a~constant~~\times~ δ(x)$

When trying to validate this in MMa, the following doesn't seem to work:

```
Simplify[-D[ϕ[x], {x, 2}] - μ^2*ϕ[x] + λ*ϕ[x]^3 == constant1*DiracDelta[x]]

(*0 == constant1*DiracDelta[x]*)
```

Is there a trick here, or is the earlier "validation" of $\phi2(x)~δ(x)$ as a solution itself misleading?

Note that $\sqrt{x^2}$ is being used for $|x|$, since MMa's `Abs[x]` didn't work for the validation.

Comment: Up to Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics), the product $ \phi2(x)~\delta(x)$ is defined if $ \phi2(x)$ is a smooth function. Therefore, $ \text{$\phi $2}(\text{x})\text{:=}\displaystyle\frac{\mu  \tanh \left(\frac{\mu  \sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{\lambda }}$, not being smooth at the origin, is not any solution of the ODE under consideration.

Comment: The solution of this equation is known. You may find it in the review of Khlyustikov I N, Buzdin A I "Localized superconductivity of twin metal crystals" Sov. Phys. Usp. 31 409–433 (1988). Alternatively you may find the solution of a somewhat more complex problem (which can be reduced to your one) published in my paper: A. Bulbich and P. Pumpjan, Nucleation on domain walls near singular phase diagram points, Ferroelectrics v.111, p.111-115 (1990). Have a look.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: It's interesting. Can you kindly write down that solution? BTW, [the references](https://ufn.ru/ru/articles/1988/5/b/references.html#ref) in  Khlyustikov I N, Buzdin A I "Localized superconductivity of twin metal crystals" Sov. Phys. Usp. 31 409–433 (1988) do not include any math one.

Comment: Why not? Equations (4.2), (4.3) and thereafter including the first integral Eq. (4.6). If you do not like that, take my paper.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: Can you present that solution explicitely? I have problems with access to the papers indicated by you.

Comment: No, I will not do this. I gave you two references out of a number of existing ones. The first paper is downloadable for free from the site. The second, however, is not.  If you need this for a serious purpose, you find papers and read them. If you do not, I do not want to spend time.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: Unfortunately, " The first paper is downloadable for free from the site" does not work for me, even after the registration at the journal site.

Comment: Do you want me to download it for you? Then give me your e-mail address.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: I repeat " Can you present that solution explicitly in this forum? I have problems with access to the papers indicated by you."

Comment: I repeat: I will not do this.  It is enough that I gave a good reference. If you do not want to go to a library, it is your business.

Answer (score 1):

For the second question(see comment) proceed as follows:

initial value problem

```
 {Derivative[2][ϕ][x] - a^2*ϕ[x] ==  k*ϕ[x]*DiracDelta[x],  
 ϕ[0]==ϕ0,ϕ'[0]==ϕp0}
```

integrating the ode in the range -b<x<b, b small

```
 Derivative[1][ϕ][b]-Derivative[1][ϕ][-b]+  2 b a^2*ϕ[2]
 ==k*ϕ[0]
```

Limit b->0

```
Derivative[1][ϕ][b]-Derivative[1][ϕ][-b] ==k*ϕ[0]
```

Here you can see the sudden change of Derivative[1][ϕ][x] due to the Dirac-impuls!

The equivalent initial value problem is

```
{Derivative[2][ϕ][x] - a^2*ϕ[x] ==0 ,  
 ϕ[0]==ϕ0,ϕ'[0]==ϕp0 +k *ϕ[0]}
```

can be solved easily

```
DSolve[{Derivative[2][ϕ][x] - a^2*ϕ[x] ==0, ϕ[0] == ϕ0, ϕ'[0] == ϕp0 +k*ϕ[0]}, ϕ, x][[1]]
(*{ϕ ->Function[{x}, (E^(-a x) (a ϕ0 + a E^(2 a x) ϕ0 - k ϕ0 +E^(2 a x) k ϕ0 - ϕp0 + E^(2 a x) ϕp0))/(2 a)]}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that it is allowed to check an ode with DiracDelta pointwise.
Though the first `True` of your simplification must be wrong.

The general solution fullfills `-D[\[Phi]2[x], {x, 2}] - \[Mu]^2*\[Phi]2[x] + \[Lambda]*\[Phi]2[x]^3==0 , x>0` . Dirac only forces a sudden change of the initial conditions.

Integrate your ode in a small range  `Element[x, {-\[CurlyEpsilon], \[CurlyEpsilon]}]`

```
-\[Phi]2'[\[CurlyEpsilon]]+\[Phi]2'[-\[CurlyEpsilon]]+ 2\[CurlyEpsilon](-\[Mu]^2*\[Phi]2[0] + \[Lambda]*\[Phi]2[0]^3) ==\[Phi]2[0]
```

Limit `\[CurlyEpsilon] -> 0` gives the new initial condition

```
\[Phi]2'[SuperPlus[0]]==\[Phi]2'[0]-\[Phi]2[0] (*RHS \[Phi][x] DiracDelta[x]*)

\[Phi]2'[SuperPlus[0]]==\[Phi]2'[0]-\[Phi]2[0] (*RHS 1  DiracDelta[x]*)
```

Comment: Thank you Ulrich. 
I am trying to trace the exact commands.
What would be the command in MMa to perform the following (or the equivalent you suggested), to get from

$\int_{-b}^{b} \phi2^{\prime \prime}(x) -a^{2}\int_{-b}^{b} \phi2(x) = k~\int_{-b}^{b} \phi2(x)~\delta(x)$

So that it leads to

(LHS) = $\lim_{b\to 0}\,\phi^{\prime}(b) - \phi2^{\prime}(- b)=[\phi2^{\prime}(0)]$

and

(RHS) = $k~\int_{-b}^{b} \phi(x)~\delta(x) = k~\phi2(0)$ = $[\phi2^{\prime}(0)]=k\,\phi2(0)$ = $\phi2(x)~=~A~e^{\mp~a~|x|}$

Comment: @user58293 Is this a new question/new ode?The initialvalue problem  `\[Phi]''[x] - a^2 \[Phi][x] == 
 k \[Phi][x] \[Delta][x], \[Phi][0] == \[Phi]0, \[Phi]'[0] == \[Phi]p0` is "equivalent" to `\[Phi]''[x] - a^2 \[Phi][x] == 0, \[Phi][0] == \[Phi]0, \[Phi]'[0] == \[Phi]p0+k \[Phi][0]` The new initial conditions follows from integrating the ode.

Comment: What's the command to go from integration with limits, and get the "new" initial condition that contains "Superplus"? The modified question in the comment is to try and capture (perhaps) a slightly more common/general case and ensure that my MMa command inputs are exactly as you intended. Thanks again Ulrich!

Comment: The command is `Integrate["ode" ,{x,-b,b},Assumption->b>0 ]` with following `Limit[...,b->0]`.  Thereby you have to help MMA a little bit to integrate the LHS.

Comment: My apologies, the steps/commands are still not obvious to me.

Comment: Integrating the ode  `\[Phi]''[x] - a^2 \[Phi][x]==k \[Phi][x] \[Delta][x]` gives `\[Phi]'[b]-\[Phi]'[-b] - a^2 2 b  \[Phi][x]==k \[Phi][0]  `, Limit `b->0` `\[Phi]'[0+]-\[Phi]'[0]  ==k \[Phi][0] ` gives the new initial condition.

Comment: Hi Ulrich, Again, sorry it's not obvious to me. The command
 
`Integrate[Derivative[2][\[Phi]][x] - a^2*\[Phi][x] = k*\[Phi][x]*DiracDelta[x], {x, -b, b}]`

results in

`ConditionalExpression[k*(-1 + 2*HeavisideTheta[b])*\[Phi][0], Element[b, Reals]]`

Of course, the limit on `b` is missing here, but how do you get the `'SuperPlus[0]` in your original answer, and what is `\[Phi]p0+k` in your initial comment? If at all possible, kindly show the complete commands with a short commentary.

Comment: The `single Equal sign ` in your Integrate command is wrong! MMA cannot simplify `Integrate[Derivative[2][\[Phi]][x] - a^2*\[Phi][x] - k*\[Phi][x]*DiracDelta[x], {x, -b, b}]` . Though I did it step by step.